# Screen artifacts on Android 6 after restore opengl application

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm working now on OpenGL application (game) which should work only in landscape mode. On Android 6 i encountered a problem that after minimize and restore application, half screen becomes game normal screen but in portrait mode and on other half of screen there some random garbage comes from gpu memory.

Whats should I do to get rid of this?

---

In AndroidManifest activity

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
```

---

In MainActivity class :

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen for landscape and portrait and set landscape mode always
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about just changing your manifest to `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

Comment: It may works, but still, what is wrong with sensor_landscape

Comment: No, didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i found out strange thing. 
When pausing/restoring application, OS is sends onSurfaceChanged notification for 3 times:

```
onSurfaceChanged(1024,768)
onSurfaceChanged(786,1024) << notice wrong dimensions!
onSurfaceChanged(1024,768)
```

Even orientation clearly specified in manifest (sensorLandscape or Landscape), android sends onSurfaceChanged notification with wrong dimensions.
So i've just dont render anything until receive onSurfaceChanged with proper dimensions (width > height). Not perfect, but it works.